# Relation between REG and NLOGTIME?

Tags: fl.formal-languages

What is known about the relation between the class of regular lanuages and NLOGTIME? Is any class contained in another one?

You have some choice of how to define NLOGTIME to get one or both inlcusions; cf., e.g., Regan & Vollmer, *Gap-languages and log-time complexity classes*, TCS 188 (1997), pp. 101–116.

Comment: sublinear time classes are very sensitive to input representation. How do you define NLOGTIME? you need linear time to even read the input. Such classes are more relevant in the context of uniform circuit classes

Comment: @Nikhil I give you a choice in doing so. Take a definition from reputable literature, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parity is a regular language not computable in NLOGTIME, or even in nonuniform AC^0. The set of all strings whose length is a power of 2 is a non-regular language computable in DLOGTIME.

Comment: Thank you. Concerning the second statement: would any accepting proviso for log-bounded computations do?

Comment: First forget about any provisa: there is only one definition of logarithmic time that you should know, the one they call *standard*. The other are esoteric historical accidents ("Sipser") or technical gimmics useful only in the context where they are equivalent to the standard definition ("Ruzzo"). Having said that, the choice makes no difference whatsoever for the language in my answer, as it does not read the input at all besides computing its length (which it can do for free in the Regan-Vollmer "provisos").

Comment: $AND(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in coNLOGTIME$ and $OR(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in NLOGTIME$ and is it known $NLOGTIME\neq coNLOGTIME$?